# Using existing ajax call we have to logout the particular user should be logged out after 15 minutes of inactivity

Tags: javascript, php, timer

**existing ajax request**

This is the ajax request which calls the web browser logout page

```
function unassignVIP(empid,emplogoff,sr,vendorName)
{
    if(emplogoff)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/index.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
            action:'Logoff',
            },
            async: false,
            success:function (response) {
            var root = document.location.origin;
            window.location.href = root+"/index.php";
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        if(empid == '')
        {
            location.reload();
        }
        else
       {
            $("#signout"+sr).html("<img src='/public/images/spinner.gif'>");
            $.ajax({
                url: "index.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    action:'unassignVIP',
                    unassign_emp_id:empid,
                    vendorName:vendorName
                },
                async: false,
                success:function (response) {
                    $("#unassignEMPTR"+empid+sr).css("display","none");
                    $("#signout"+sr).html("");
                    alert("Lead has Unassigned from " +empid);
                },beforeSend:function() {
                //$("#signout"+sr).html("<img src='/public/images/spinner.gif'>");
            }
        });
        }
    }
}
```

Tried implementation:

```
setLogoutTimer();
function setLogoutTimer() {
    var myTimeout;
    if (window.sessionStorage) {

        myTimeout = sessionStorage.timeoutVar;
        if (myTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(myTimeout);
        }

    }

    myTimeout = setTimeout(function () { logoutNow(); }, 5000);  //adjust the time. 
    if (window.sessionStorage) {
        sessionStorage.timeoutVar = myTimeout;
    }
}

function logoutNow() {
    if (window.sessionStorage) {
        sessionStorage.timeoutVar = null;
    }
//MAKE AN AJAX CALL HERE THAT WILL CALL YOUR FUNCTION IN
```

// CONTROLLER AND RETURN A URL TO ANOTHER PAGE

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/index.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            action:'Logoff',
        },
        async: false,
        success:function (response) {
            var root = document.location.origin;
            window.location.href = root+"/index.php";
        }
    });
}
```

i have tried the above implementation but it's not reflecting the changes in the web browser can you please correct the code and provide suggestions thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not to track a logout process on server?
Also please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: No i need for web browser